# accessing eXist db through Java

Tags: java, exist-db

I need to develop an online assessment system for evaluating xqueries. I am trying to use eXist db xml database. I am developing the web app in Java, struts2 and apache tomcat server.
How can i upload xml schema document and xml instance document using java ? Also i should be able to fire an xquery on the xml document and get the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

eXist-db has REST, XML-RPC, XML-DB, and other APIs.  Sample code is available from the Developer's Guide documentation: http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/devguide.xml.  For further questions about eXist-db, I'd welcome you to join the exist-open mailing list; see https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/exist-open.